# Aerospike Config specific to setName

Tags: caching, aerospike

I am new to Aerospike..
My namespace has multiple sets.
I am trying to set different TTLs for different sets in my aerospike dB namespace.

I do not want to use the default-ttl assigned to the namespace, instead I want to set it for each set.

my config

```
namespace test {
        replication-factor 1
        memory-size 1G
        default-ttl 0 
}
```

i referred to this link https://docs.aerospike.com/server/operations/configure, where it is stating that set specific record policies can be set.

```
namespace <name> {       # Define namespace record policies and storage engine
    storage {}           # Configure persistence or lack of persistence
    set {}               # (Optional) Set specific record policies
}
```

but i am not sure what field should i use to set the ttl for each set. Say, i have two sets in this 'test' namespace named - `order` and `name` and i want their ttls to be 2hrs and 6 hours respectively.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All records in aeropsike belong to a namespace, set is just a metadata, like a tag, on the record. default-ttl is the record's remaining life if the client does not specify at create or update. You cannot assign default-ttl *by set* in the server configuration. (There are some other set specific config parameters, for e.g. *disable-eviction*, *enable-index* that are implemented, *default-ttl* is not one of them.) But you can achieve the same by writing it in your client application.

For each set you can use a different write policy and in that write policy define the ttl for creating or updating records in that specific set. For e.g. in Java client, it is called WritePolicy.expiration, in seconds.  In your specific case, you could do 2 hours default-ttl as server config - so orders will get that as default, for *name*, in client, when creating or updating records in *name* set, you override server default to 6 hours using WritePolicy.expiration = 3600.

Comment: This is the right answer and the most flexible one, just wanted to add that if you are using Spring Data Aerospike you can use @Document annotation on a class/persistent object and to specify expiration/TTL at the set level.

For example:
`@Document(collection = “set-name”, expiration = 1, expirationUnit = TimeUnit.DAYS)`
collection = set name.
expiration = TTL for the set.
expirationUnit = Time units for the TTL configuration.